# ApplicationInsights Telemetry exception in system automation

Tags: azure-application-insights

In a project we call Powershell scripts in C#.

```
    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
    {
        runspace.Open();
        var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        ..
        pipeline.Invoke();
        ..
```

This works without any issues until ApplicationInsights Telemetry package is installed. Version 1.2.x had this issue so I upgrade to 2.0.0, but still the same exception.

Stacktrace below:

> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException
>
> The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper' threw an
>   exception. System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The
>   type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper'
>   threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Type
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule,
>   Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not implement the required
>   interface
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryModule.    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.CreateInstance(Type
>   interfaceType, String typeName)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement
>   definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstances[T](XElement
>   definition, ICollection`1 instances)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement
>   definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadProperties(XElement
>   instanceDefinition, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement
>   definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.get_Active()
>   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient..ctor()    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper..cctor()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper.GenerateSha256HashString(String
>   originInput)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.InitializeQosEvent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.BeginProcessing()
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Profile.SubscriptionCmdletBase.BeginProcessing()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()    at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
>   input)

For now I deinstalled the NuGet package for ApplicationInsights, because I don't know a solution. Perhaps it's a bug in ApplicationInsights?

Comment: an error like 'x does not implement y' runtime generally to me implies that you might have different versions of the sdks installed, or as part of your deployment you might also have older/other versions of some of these binaries deployed to your site?

Comment: Perhaps yes, but for now I just do not use Application Insights, as there is no requirement for it and it was just for the fun of it on my side. I cannot wait until "docker containers" or something are the standard for this. Windows 2016 and no more machine issues I hope.